# Spring boot Angular Application project runs compiled html... how do I 'recompile'

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, spring-mvc

**Setting: I inherited a project that I need to update the UI for**

I have a spring boot application that has an angular front end.

If I make UI changes in the front end, code at `src/main/web/`, they do not appear in the application that launches when I run `mvn spring-boot:run`

The application refers to files in the `src/main/resources/static/` instead. This folder seems to contain 'compiled` front end scripts.

**Question**

I am trying to recompile `src/main/web/` files into the `src/main/resources/static/`, how do I do that?

**Notes**

I have tried

```
bower install
npm install
mvn install
mvn clean
```

They have grunt here. Running the `grunt serve` command will show my updated front end files, this, in a sense "works", but mvn spring boot runs the full application and it is necessary that this command works.

An `ls` of the main directory shows:

```
Gruntfile.js        bower_components    package-lock.json   pom.xml         src
README.md       package.json            swagger.json
bower.json      node_modules        packageOld.json         target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is being compiled by `grunt`, not `bower` or `npm` or `mvn`.

`grunt clean build`